# Given a known polynomial, how can I calculate the error/residuals with the same polynomial on a different set of data?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a first set of data (x1 and y1 below) that I fit a third degree polynomial to, and it gives me the polynomial parameters, `params = np.array([ 1.63896794, -0.73527506,  0.09931817, -0.00301105])`. Is there way to now keep this polynomial, and fit a new set of data to it and find the residuals/error? If it helps, I'm essentially wanting to ask, if I believe the trend in the first data set is real, how well does the second data set adhere to this trend?

```
x1 = np.array([0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.625, 0.75 , 0.875, 1. , 1.125,1.25 , 1.375, 1.5 , 1.625, 1.75 , 1.875, 2. , 2.125, 2.25 ,2.375, 2.5  , 2.625, 2.75 , 2.875, 3. , 3.125, 3.25 , 3.375, 3.5 , 3.625, 3.75 , 3.875, 4. , 4.125, 4.25 , 4.375, 4.5  ,4.625, 4.75 , 4.875, 5. , 5.125, 5.25 , 5.375, 5.5])

y1 = np.array([1.54860452, 1.46905547, 1.4023793 , 1.33886804, 1.27407649,1.20408011, 1.12253819, 1.        , 0.81541134, 0.70050688,0.6149342 , 0.54775906, 0.49332673, 0.44821328, 0.41016773,0.37762976, 0.34947586, 0.324873  , 0.30318878, 0.28393363,0.26672221, 0.25124682, 0.23725866, 0.22455429, 0.21296573,0.20235298, 0.19259846, 0.18360268, 0.17528084, 0.16756028,0.16037834, 0.15368068, 0.14742001, 0.14155489, 0.13604895,0.13087005, 0.12598975, 0.12138275, 0.11702648, 0.11290075,0.10898742, 0.10527018, 0.10173429, 0.09836641])
```

Comment: have you tried `np.remainder(x1,y1)`

Comment: How does this help me then see the error when I fit the same polynomial to a different set of data?

Comment: Sorry, where have I left my mind.. What you are looking for is `np.polyfit(x1, y1, deg, full=True)`    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721053/whats-the-error-of-numpy-polyfit

Comment: No worries, it's the weekend after all. However, I don't want to know the error of the fitting of x1 and y1. I would like to know the error of a separate data set, x2,y2, when it is compared to the polynomial described by x1, y1. Is there a function to do this? I have just realised I can just take the parameters from np.polyfit(x1, y1, deg), and calculate the error of each of the data points x2,y2 myself. Do you know of a function when you input the polynomial parameters and data, and it gives you the error?

Comment: How did you for the polynomial? There are a few options, and they return results that are interpreted very differently.

Comment: Here is basically a duplicate of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29632733/2988730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a fitted polynomial from the set `{x1, y1}`, you can just construct a function (polynomial, say `P1(x)`) using the coefficients you have, and for a set `{x2, y2}` you can evaluate the polynomial at all the `{x2}` and then find the differences between all the `{P1(x2)}` and `{y2}`. Both these steps can be achieved vectorially.
Doesn't that serve your purpose?

Comment: Yes it does. I see now I was being lazy and hoping there was a function to do it all for me rather than just thinking for myself. Even worse, I just had to input values into the polynomial function that I'd used... Thanks for your response.

Comment: @ArthurRadley. There likely is such a function (two at most). Consider updating your question.